# Catch `Exception` globally in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, exception, fastapi

I am trying to catch unhandled exceptions at global level. So somewhere in `main.py` file I have the below:

```py
@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def exception_callback(request: Request, exc: Exception):
  logger.error(exc.detail)
```

But the above method is never executed. However, if I write a custom exception and try to catch it (as shown below), it works just fine.

```py
class MyException(Exception):
  #some code

@app.exception_handler(MyException)
async def exception_callback(request: Request, exc: MyException):
  logger.error(exc.detail)
```

I have gone through [Catch exception type of Exception and process body request #575](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/575). But this bug talks about accessing request body. After seeing this bug, I feel it should be possible to catch `Exception`.
FastAPI version I am using is: `fastapi>=0.52.0`.

Thanks in advance :)

---

### *Update*

There are multiple answers, I am thankful to all the readers and authors here.
I was revisiting this solution in my application. Now I see that I needed to set `debug=False`, default it's `False`, but I had it set to `True` in

```
server = FastAPI(
    title=app_settings.PROJECT_NAME,
    version=app_settings.VERSION,
)
```

It seems that I missed it when @iedmrc commented on answer given by @Kavindu Dodanduwa.

Comment: Ajeet I must say that I cannot reproduce your problems using fastapi[all]==0.65.1  and starlette==0.14.2 . I have a project with the exact setup as you describe except that I have an additional `return JSONResponse(status_code=500, content={"message": "internal server error"})` in `exception_callback`.

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In case you want to capture all unhandled exceptions (internal server error), there's a very simple way of doing it. [Documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import Response
from traceback import print_exception

app = FastAPI()

async def catch_exceptions_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception:
        # you probably want some kind of logging here
        print_exception(e)
        return Response("Internal server error", status_code=500)

app.middleware('http')(catch_exceptions_middleware)
```

Make sure you place this middleware before everything else.

Comment: This one awaits for all task to finish. Thus, it prevents to schedule a task to run in background.

Comment: the 'middleware' example doesn't work for me but the usage of 'route' in the official documentation works like a charm https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#accessing-the-request-body-in-an-exception-handler

Comment: We are using Peewee as ORM tool. Peewee does not support async. How can we still use this?

Answer (score 16):

You can do something like this. It should return a json object with your custom error message also works in debugger mode.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    # Change here to Logger
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=500,
        content={
            "message": (
                f"Failed method {request.method} at URL {request.url}."
                f" Exception message is {exc!r}."
            )
        },
    )
```

Comment: This is a great solution that actually worked for me.

Comment: As mentioned above this still produces an "Exception in ASGI application_"

Comment: @Chris Now it must be fixed since version 0.15. I did not test it yet.

Answer (score 9):

Adding a custom `APIRoute` can be also be used to handle global exceptions. The advantage of this approach is that if a http exception is raised from the custom route it will be handled by default Starlette's error handlers:

```py
from typing import Callable

from fastapi import Request, Response, HTTPException, APIRouter, FastAPI
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from .logging import logger


class RouteErrorHandler(APIRoute):
    """Custom APIRoute that handles application errors and exceptions"""

    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            try:
                return await original_route_handler(request)
            except Exception as ex:
                if isinstance(ex, HTTPException):
                    raise ex
                logger.exception("uncaught error")
                # wrap error into pretty 500 exception
                raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(ex))

        return custom_route_handler


router = APIRouter(route_class=RouteErrorHandler)

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)
```

Worked for me with fastapi==0.68.1.

More on custom routes: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/

Comment: Note that `@app.exception_handler`s appear to be invoked *after* the route handler is called. You will need to check for and `raise` any other exception type that you have define an app exception handler for, e.g. `RequestValidationError`.

Answer (score 6):

It is a known issue on the Fastapi and Starlette.

I am trying to capture the StarletteHTTPException globally by a following simple sample.

```py
import uvicorn

from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def exception_callback(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    print("test")
    return JSONResponse({"detail": "test_error"}, status_code=500)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("test:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=1111, reload=True)
```

It works. I open the browser and call the endpoint / and try to access http://127.0.0.1:1111/ , it will return the json {"detail":"test_error"} with HTTP code "500 Internal Server Error" .

[image: 500 on browser]
[image: 500 in IDE]

However, when I only changed StarletteHTTPException to Exception in the @app.exception_handler,

```py
import uvicorn

from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def exception_callback(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    print("test")
    return JSONResponse({"detail": "test_error"}, status_code=500)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("test:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=1111, reload=True)
```

The method exception_callback could not capture the StarletteHTTPException when I accessed the http://127.0.0.1:1111/ . It reported 404 error.

[image: 404 on browser]
[image: 404 in IDE]

The excepted behaviour should be: StarletteHTTPException error could be captured by the method exception_handler decorated by Exception because StarletteHTTPException is the child class of Exception.

However, it is a known issue reported in Fastapi and Starlette

- https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2750
- https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2683
- https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/1129

So we are not able to acheieve the goal currently.

Comment: This was fixed by Starlette

Answer (score 4):

First I invite to get familiar with exception base classes in python. You can read them in the document [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Secondly, read through fastApi default exception overriding behaviour [Override the default exception handlers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-the-default-exception-handlers)

What you must understand is that `@app.exception_handler` accepts any Exception or child classes derived from `Exception`. For example `RequestValidationError` is a subclass of python built in `ValueError` which itself a subclass of `Exception`.

So you must design your own exceptions or throw available exceptions with this background. I guess what went wrong is with your logger `logger.error(exc.detail)` by either not having a detail field or not having a proper logger configuration.

Sample code :

```
@app.get("/")
def read_root(response: Response):
    raise ArithmeticError("Divide by zero")


@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    print(str(exc))
    return PlainTextResponse("Something went wrong", status_code=400)
```

Output :

A stdout entry and a response with `Something went wrong`

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. Unless I change the exception handler to @app.exception_handler(ArithmeticError), which is what OP is describing (parent class Exception not catching derived classes). I am not sure if this is a working solution.

Comment: For me it works (I get to the handler for ValueError) but remember that this doesn't catch an exception so exception will propagate further.

Comment: First I invite you to get familiar with the question. You can realize that the OP is already doing same thing that you suggested. Secondly read through what exactly OP is asking. They are proficient and don't need consultation on Python basics. What you must understand is that "debug" mode of FastAPI is catching exceptions prior to such a handler.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to catch exceptions without the "Exception in ASGI application_" by using a middleware. Not sure if this has some other side effect but for me that works fine! @iedmrc

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def exception_handling(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception as exc:
        log.error("Do some logging here")
        return JSONResponse(status_code=500, content="some content")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for global handler for fast api for giving custome message for 429 status code i found and implemented, working fine for me
@app.exception_handler(429)
async def ratelimit_handler(request: Request, exc: Exception):
return JSONResponse({'message': "You have exceeded your request quota. Kindly try after some time.", 'status': 'failed'})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `starlette.middleware.exceptions.ExceptionMiddleware`, then override `_lookup_exception_handler()`.

This answer was inspired by reading this method: `starlette.applications.Starlette.build_middleware_stack()`

Example:

```
class GenericExceptionMiddleware(ExceptionMiddleware):

    # Intentional: Defer __init__(...) to super class ExceptionMiddleware

    # @Override(ExceptionMiddleware)
    def _lookup_exception_handler(
            self, exc: Exception
    ) -> Optional[Callable]:
        if isinstance(exc, HTTPException):
            return self.__http_exception_handler
        else:
            return self.__exception_handler

    @classmethod
    async def __http_exception_handler(cls, request: fastapi.Request,  # @Debug
                                       ex: HTTPException):

        log.error("Unexpected error", cause=ex)
        resp = PlainTextResponse(content=f"Unexpected error: {ex.detail}"
                                         f"\n"
                                         f"\nException stack trace"
                                         f"\n====================="
                                         f"\n{ex}", # Improve to add full stack trace
                                 status_code=ex.status_code)
        return resp

    @classmethod
    async def __exception_handler(cls, request: fastapi.Request,  # @Debug
                                  ex: Exception):

        log.error("Unexpected error", cause=ex)
        resp = PlainTextResponse(content=f"Unexpected error: {ex}"
                                         f"\n"
                                         f"\nException stack trace"
                                         f"\n====================="
                                         f"\n{ex}", # Improve to add full stack trace
                                 status_code=fastapi.status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        return resp
```

Sample usage:

```
fast_api = FastAPI()
fast_api.add_middleware(GenericExceptionMiddleware, debug=fast_api.debug)
```